# Identify the grammatical name and function of each of the expressions italicized/bolded below

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, clauses

1. I met the **only student of the newly established Technical University located at Ibadan.**
2. My friend is a man **to beat.**
3. The boy who stole the book is running **like a deer.**
4. **Sighting the owner of the book**, Kola ran away.
5. **Backbiting and gossiping** led him to prison.
6. **The fact that he showed you love** is not enough to tell him your secrets.

Comment: 1.Noun Phrase functioning as object of the transitive verb _met_. 2.Gerundial infinitive (here functioning as adjective and modifying _man_) 3.Adverb phrase qualifying the verb _running_ 4.Participle phrase modifying _Kola_ 5.Gerund phrase functioning as noun 6.Noun Clause functioning as subject of the sentence.

Comment: This is all traditional stuff. Modern grammarians often employ other labels for these.

Comment: Correction: For 2 and 5,the functions performed are those of a modifier and a subject, respectively.  Parts of speech are not functions.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I met **the only student of the newly established Technical University***
> ***located at Ibadan***.
>
> [2] *My friend is a man **to beat**.*
>
> [3] *The boy who stole the book is running **like a deer**.*
>
> [4] ***Sighting the owner of the book**, Kola ran away*.
>
> [5] ***Backbiting and gossiping** led him to prison.*
>
> [6] ***The fact that he showed you love** is not enough to tell him your*
> *secrets*.

[1]: Noun phrase functioning as object of "met".

[2]: Infinitival clause functioning as modifier of "man".

[3]: Preposition phrase functioning complement of "running".

[4]: Gerund-participial clause functioning as depictive adjunct.

[5]: Gerund-participial clauses (or gerundial nouns) functioning as subject.

[6]: Noun phrase functioning as subject.

Answer (score -2):

> 1.I met **the only student of the newly established Technical University located at Ibadan.**

An adverb phrase that expounds on the action (in this case, whom the subject had *met*.)

> 2. My friend is a man **to beat**.

This is a verbal(infinitive) that describes the subject, a noun.

> 3. The boy who stole the book is running *like a deer.*

A prepositional phrase that shows some sort of relationship between the deer and the boy.

> 4. **Sighting the owner of the book**, Kola ran away.

A participle phrase that acts like an adjective describing why Kola ran away. (Don't mistake this with a gerund phrase which acts like a noun.)

> 5. **Backbiting and gossiping** led him to prison.

These are nouns(gerunds --> verb+ing), which show some activity.

> 6. **The fact that he showed you love** is not enough to tell him your secrets.

I'm not quite sure about this one, but I think it's a noun phrase that's acting as a subject to the verb 'is'.